# Seaborn does not give me a proper plot and remove some tick labels automatically

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

It is my first question as a Python newbie and I will appreciate your help. 
I am trying to plot a Pandas' df using seaborn. While my code works properly with most of dfs, it does not give me a proper plot when the number of tick labels increases. I am wondering if it is something related to that number or something is wrong with my code.

By testing I figured out when the number of labels are less than 15, it works properly but when it goes around 30, some of labels are removed. I want the plot to show all labels.

Here is my code:

```
#Libs
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import tkinter as tk
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


#Tweet type and Tone
tweet_tone= pd.crosstab([final_codes_eng.Cluster, final_codes_eng.Tweet_type], final_codes_eng.Tone)

tweet_tone_heat= sns.heatmap(tweet_tone, cmap="terrain_r", annot_kws={"size": 4}, annot=True, fmt='.0f' )
plt.ylabel('Networked Public/Tweet Type', fontsize = 11, x=0, y=0.5, labelpad=25 )
plt.xlabel('Tone',fontsize = 12)
plt.text(-3,-0.4, "Tone in Networked Public Based on Tweet Type(Total Network)", fontsize = 12, color='White', fontstyle='oblique')
```

As I used it with similar dfs, I expected to get a full plot but the final result is strange not showing some labels. Here is the final plot: 
http://s4.picofile.com/file/8369417626/sample.jpg
as you can see there are some rows which their labels are removed.

Comment: Use `yticklabels=True` to show all ticklabels.

Comment: Thanks. It solved the problem.